# Count non null variable

Tags: php

I want to count non `NULL` string in for each loop.

```
$imgCount = 0;

foreach($ads as $ad) { // it return 3 $ad

if(!empty($ad["img1"])){
$imgCount += $imgCount + 1; // img1 has data
} else if(!empty($ad["img2"])){    
$imgCount += $imgCount + 1; // img2 has data
} else if(!empty($ad["img3"])){   
$imgCount += $imgCount + 1; // img3 is NULL
}

echo $imgCount;

}
```

But it return wrong number, all `img` column type are `NULL`. it should return `2`, if all are NULL should return `0` and if all there has data should return `3`. Also `$imgCount++` not worked.

what i have done wrong?

**Edit:** Example

consider `$ad["img1"]` has value
`$ad["img2"]` has value
`$ad["img1"]` is NULL

it should count non null, and return 2.

**Edit:** full `var_dump`

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["img1"]=>
    string(23) "2017-11-01_9773424337_1"
    ["img2"]=>
    NULL
    ["img3"]=>
    NULL
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["img1"]=>
    string(23) "2017-11-11_1082077846_1"
    ["img2"]=>
    NULL
    ["img3"]=>
    NULL
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["img1"]=>
    string(23) "2017-11-11_4665330406_1"
    ["img2"]=>
    string(23) "2017-11-11_4665330406_2"
    ["img3"]=>
    string(23) "2017-11-11_4665330406_3"
  }
}
```

Comment: please also show your array $ads

Comment: @DhairyaLakhera check on the answer below, in comment. Thanks

Comment: @DhairyaLakhera i updated my question with full var dump result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$imgCount = 0;

foreach($ads as $ad) { 

    if(!empty($ad["img1"])){
        $imgCount++;
    } 
    if(!empty($ad["img2"])){    
        $imgCount++;
    } 
    if(!empty($ad["img3"])){   
        $imgCount++;
    } 

echo $imgCount;

}
```

OR if you want to referesh the $imgCount value on each loop then you can try another code :

```
foreach($ads as $ad) { 
    $imgCount = 0; //put $imgCount inside the loop to refresh the counter to 0 again.

    if(!empty($ad["img1"])){
        $imgCount++;
    } 
    if(!empty($ad["img2"])){    
        $imgCount++;
    } 
    if(!empty($ad["img3"])){   
        $imgCount++;
    } 

    echo $imgCount;

}
```

Comment: once try to use !is_null($ad) instead of !empty($ad)

Comment: that is weird but still same, wrong number. according to var dump in question, it return 1 (has one image) / 2 (has one images) / 5 (hast three images)

Comment: @martian i have updated again. now i provided two alternative code. try to put $imgCount = 0; inside the loop

Comment: Finally it works.. Thanks a lot. i thought `$i=0` should always be outside the loop..

Comment: you had two mistake. First you used $count=0 outside loop and you used else...if

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the value of the image count to itself, and then adding 1, which gives you the wrong result.

Try this, I have even optimized the code a bit:

```
$imgCount = 0;

foreach( $ads as $key => $ad ) {

        if( substr( $key, 0, 3 ) !== "img" ) {

            continue;

        }

        if( !empty( $ad ) ) {

            $imgCount++;

        }

}
```

Comment: It return wrong number,  for example one item has 3 image and not NULL but it return 5 // another item have 1 image return 2 // another have 1 image return 1.

Comment: Can you give me a var_dump of the array?

Comment: `var_dump` of `$ads` ? yes, here is `["img1"]=>
    string(23) "2017-11-01_9773424337_1"
    ["img2"]=>
    NULL
    ["img3"]=>
    NULL` this should return 1

Comment: I updated my answer. Tested it myself, it should be working.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `if..else if..else if` when actually you want to possibly execute all three if's, not just the first matching one. Also the comment on you adding the variable to itself is correct.
For a solution more in line with original code, try:

```
if(!empty($ad["img1"])){
  $imgCount += 1; // img1 has data
}
if(!empty($ad["img2"])){    
  $imgCount += 1; // img2 has data
}
if(!empty($ad["img3"])){   
  $imgCount += 1; // img3 is NULL
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Jesse has the right logic, but can be done in a simplier way. You can have single loop.

See sample  tested code.

```
$ads = array(
    'img1'=> 'Sample01',
    'img2'=> 'Sample02',
    'img3'=> null,
);

$imgCount = 0;

foreach( $ads as $key => $ad ) {
    if( substr( $key, 0, 3 ) !== "img" ) {
        continue;
    }
    if( !empty( $ad ) ) {
        $imgCount++;
    }

}

echo $imgCount;
```

Comment: all returns `0`